# Addition of functions inside of Big O?

Tags: function, big-o, addition

What does it mean when there is an addition of functions inside of the Big O, e.g. O(n + nlogn). Would this be different than O(nlogn) since it is the bigger function?

Comment: No, it would be the same. You need to leave multiple functions inside when they depend on different parameters though, e.g. `O(n+m^3)`

Answer (score 0):

With asymptotic notation, you are effectively trying to set a bound that you know your algorithm will not cross. Big-O is the worst that your algorithm will perform. In your case, *O(n + log(n))* turns into *O(nlog(n))* because *nlog(n)* grows the fastest as *n* approaches infinity. This is why you are usually taught that you can discount the smaller function, at least when measuring Big-O. There are also Big-Theta (what your average run-time will be) and Big-Omega (the best case scenario).